# Two definitions on Borel sets of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ agrees

Tags: measure-theory

This measure theory question asks me to prove that if $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ then the two following $\sigma$-algebras on $X$,
$$
\mathcal{M} = \{E = X\cap B: B\in \mathcal{B}_n\}
$$
$$
\mathcal{N} = \langle X\cap O: O ~\text{open in}~ \mathbb{R}^n\rangle
$$
agree $(N$ here is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the subspace topology of $X)$. I have shown that $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and contains $N$. But I don't know how to show the other direction $($both elements in $\mathcal{M}$, i.e. $X\cap B$ and $\mathcal{N}$ are a bit complicated to me$)$.

How to prove that $\mathcal{M}\subset \mathcal{N}$? Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** I edit this question to prove for a more general result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{A\subseteq \mathbb R: X\cap A \in \mathcal N\}$  is a $\sigma-$ algebra on $\mathbb R^{n}$ which contains all open sets in $\mathbb R^{n}$. Hence, it contains all Borel sets in $\mathbb R^{n}$.  [Note: $X\cap A^{c}=X\setminus (X\cap A)$].

Comment: This is a really clever way to prove the other direction. Thank you!